# Nest JS application is not starting with TypeORM 0.3 Datasource method TypeORM (0.3.10)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nest, nestjs-typeorm

I have a Nest JS application using TypeORM 0.3 version. The application is not starting with the new DataSource configuration.

Error: Nest JS application is not starting with Data source new typeORM 0.3 way.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

Blocked in below error. Not sure how to fix it.
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.
Potential solutions:

- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmCoreModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmCoreModule?

Code:

src/db/data-source.ts

````
This contains TypeORM 0.3 Data source connection file

```
import {
  TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions,
  TypeOrmModuleOptions,
} from '@nestjs/typeorm';

// import { Tag } from '@app/tag/tag.entity';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: +process.env.PORT,
  username: process.env.USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  migrations: [__dirname + '\\migrations\\**\\*{.ts,.js}'],

  // entities: [Tag],
  // entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  // migrations: [__dirname + '/../database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  //   cli: {
  //     migrationsDir: __dirname + '/../database/migrations',
  //   },
  // extra: {
  //   charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  // },
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
export default dataSource;
```
````

In Nest JS App module file imported Data source and added to imports as suggested in [official documentation](https://github.com/AmirMustafa/nestjs-medium-clone/issues/1)

Any help will be appreciated team.

**Screenshots**: [Code and Error](https://github.com/AmirMustafa/nestjs-medium-clone/issues/1) 
**Code:** [commit](https://github.com/AmirMustafa/nestjs-medium-clone/commit/947b8d3026a73c509c3f465ab347cc6aa7d69177)

````
src/app.module.ts
```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { dataSourceOptions } from '@app/db/data-source';
import { AppController } from '@app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from '@app/app.service';
import { TagModule } from '@app/tag/tag.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
// import { Tag } from './tag/tag.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(dataSourceOptions),
    // forwardRef(() => TagModule),
    // TagModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

```
````

Comment: facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the datasource outside of the modules? If not then you can use same old method using `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()`. If you're using outside of the modules for sessions, use like this.

```
// main.ts
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm/out';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import * as session from 'express-session';

async function bootstrap() {
  const sessionRepository = app.get(DataSource).getRepository(SessionsEntity);

  app.use(
    session({
      // other session options
      store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionRepository),
    }),
  );
}
bootstrap();
```